# How does google mail implement the new upload functionality with html5?

Tags: .net, wcf, file-upload, html

I noticed while using Firefox and Chrome that in gmail I can now simply drag & drop multiple files in a new mail. Then suddenly a bar grows and I can drop the files there and they get uploaded. I think this is html5 functionality.

Does anyone have information about how to implement this? What is needed from html5 and how to handle it server side (.NET).

Answer (score 1):

The html5 drag&drop feature needs to be implemented only client-side(in browser). After dragging the file into a drop field you could send a http query for uploading the dropped file to the server and the server wouldn't even have a clue that this file was dropped in some way and will treat it as normal file upload query.

I found this great post about html5 drag&drop feature: http://decafbad.com/blog/2009/07/15/html5-drag-and-drop
There are even understandable examples for uploading files. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: It only allows dragging and dropping from within the same window. What I am after is dragging from windows explorer into the browser and there drop it and the uploading starts.

Comment: Oh...sorry, I've under checked it. I've never implemented such a feature, but found someone who investigated how did Google exactly make it: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/gmail-upload